# How to post other form fields with dropzone js?

Tags: php, forms, post, upload, dropzone.js

I have an `HTML` form with a `dropzone js` file upload. I want to post other form field information with the file. I tried this code,

**HTML**

```
<script src="dropzone/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropzone/dist/dropzone.css">

<form role="form" id="my-awesome-dropzone" method="post" action="photos/post"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Title" >
     <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location">
     <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <input type="button" value="Post" id="post-btn">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    url: "photos/post",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    parallelUploads:3,
    maxFiles : 3,       
});

$('#post-btn').on('click',function(){        
     myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

But using this code I can only post the image not the title and location. How can I post the the title and location values with the upload information ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  // Will send the filesize along with the file as POST data.
  formData.append("filesize", file.size);
});
```